# How to group items by index? C# LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, grouping

Suppose I have

```
var input = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

How do I get them grouped into pairs?

```
var output = new int[][] { new int[] { 0, 1 }, new int[] { 2, 3 }, new int[] { 4, 5 } };
```

Preferably using LINQ

Comment: Your example doesn't show how 0,1 are related so that they could be grouped.  Or are you just grouping them sequentially in pairs?

Comment: I want to group sequentially in pairs

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
input
   .Select((value, index) => new { PairNum = index / 2, value })
   .GroupBy(pair => pair.PairNum)
   .Select(grp => grp.Select(g => g.value).ToArray())
   .ToArray()
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably not applicable to you, but you could use the new Zip method in C# 4.0

```
var input = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable evens = input.Where((element, index) => index % 2 == 0);
IEnumerable odds = input.Where((element, index) => index % 2 == 1);
var results = evens.Zip(odds, (e, o) => new[] { e, o }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [ToLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb549211(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
input
    .Select((number, index) => new { index , number})
    .ToLookup(_ => _.index / 2, _ => _.number)
    .Select(_ => _.ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Using [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
input
    .Zip(input.Skip(1), (_, __) => new[] {_, __})
    .Where((_, index) => index % 2 == 0)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var indexedNumbers = input.Select((number, index) => new { Index = index, Number = number });

var pairs =
    from indexedNumber in indexedNumbers
    group indexedNumber by indexedNumber.Index / 2 into indexedNumberPair
    select indexedNumberPair.Select(indexedNumber => indexedNumber.Number);

var arrays = pairs.Select(pair => pair.ToArray()).ToArray();
```