# Selecting every 2 ints from an int[] and combining them into an array of uint64[] using Lamda expression

Tags: c#, arrays, join, lambda, casting

The third party API I am using returns an array of type int[]. Let's call it readWords as per:

```
int[] readWords
```

However, this retuned array should have been a uint[].
So I am doing the following casting:

```
Uint Ulongs = readWords(item => (ulong)item).ToArray();
```

Now, the problem is that in some cases I need to combine every 2 received int words into an Uint64[].
What would be an elegant way of doing this using lambda expressions?

I was thinking of using something of the sort, but I am not sure how to:

```
Uint64[] longs = readWords
                 .Select(every 2 int into 1 Uint64)
                 .GroupBy(x => ...);
```

Note that every 2 ints must be combined into an Uint64 as per:

```
Uint64 word0 = (readWords[0] & 0xFFFFFF) | ((Uint64)(readWords[1] & 0xFFFFFF) << 24);
```

Example, if we have:

```
int[] = new int[]{0x00123456, 0x00456789}
```

The resulting combined 64-bit word must be:

```
0x0000456789123456
```

Comment: Grouping like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290451/how-to-group-items-by-index-c-sharp-linq

Comment: Note that your resultant values can never be negative (the top bit cannot be set), therefore you can always convert them to `long` rather than`ulong`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Every combination* of two items is a *Cartesian Join* (`readWords` with *itself*):

```
int[] readWords = ...

var result = readWords
  .SelectMany(left => readWords
     .Select(right => /*TODO: put left and right combination here*/))
  .ToArray();
```

In order to create `ulong` from `2` `int`s, let's use bit manipulations you've provided:

```
(lelf, right) => unchecked(((ulong)left & 0xFFFFFF) | ((ulong)(right & 0xFFFFFF) << 24)))
```

Finally

```
int[] readWords = ...

var result = readWords
  .SelectMany(left => readWords
     .Select(right => unchecked(((ulong)left & 0xFFFFFF) | 
                                ((ulong)(right & 0xFFFFFF) << 24))))
  .ToArray(); // materialization, if required
```

Let's have a look:

```
  int[] readWords = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

  var result = readWords
    .SelectMany(left => readWords
      .Select(right => unchecked(((ulong)left & 0xFFFFFF) | 
                                 ((ulong)(right & 0xFFFFFF) << 24))))
    .ToArray();

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    result.Select(item => item.ToString("x16")));

  Console.WriteLine(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
0000000001000001
0000000002000001
0000000003000001
0000000001000002
0000000002000002
0000000003000002
0000000001000003
0000000002000003
0000000003000003
```

**Edit:** Same idea (*Cartesian Join*) if you want to combine, say, every *even* item with every *odd* one:

```
  int[] readWords = new int[] { 0x00123456, 0x00456789 };

  var result = readWords
    .Where((value, index) => index % 2 == 0)    // even indexes only
    .SelectMany(left => readWords
      .Where((value, index) => index % 2 != 0)  // odd indexes only
      .Select(right => unchecked(((ulong)left & 0xFFFFFF) | 
                                 ((ulong)(right & 0xFFFFFF) << 24))))
    .ToArray();

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    result.Select(item => item.ToString("x16")));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  0000456789123456
```

**Edit 2:** However, no *Cartesian Join* is here if you want to combine

```
 item_0 and item_1,
 item_2 and item_3,
 item_4 and item_5,
...
item_2N and item_2N+1,
...
```

(see comments below; please, note, that we don't combine *every* items) just a simple `Select`:

```
var result = Enumerable
  .Range(0, readWords.Length / 2)
  .Select(index => new {
     left = readWords[2 * index],
     right = readWords[2 * index + 1]
   })
  .Select(pair => unchecked(((ulong)(pair.left) & 0xFFFFFF) | 
                            ((ulong)(pair.right & 0xFFFFFF) << 24)))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, not quite the combination I am after, but it helps. See example in my question (just edited).

Comment: Oh, I see, you get every combination instead of combining every 2 words (step of 2)

Comment: @progLearner: so when given an `int[]` array with, say `{1, 2, 3}`, which *combinations* we want to obtain, please? You've put it as "*every* `2` received int words", that's why I return every possible pairs: `{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}`

Comment: Thank you for your great answers. So for instance if you have the array {1, 2, 3, 4}, we have to combine 1 with 2 and 3 with 4.

Comment: @progLearner: I see; in this case we don't have *every* words to combine, no *Cartesian Join*, but a simple `Select`

Answer (score 0):

Just doing it in a loop without using Linq is perfectly OK, so I would recommend just doing that.

However, if you do want to use Linq you can write a helper method that converts an `IList<int>` to an `IEnumerable<ulong>` and use that with Linq's `ToArray()` like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<ulong> Combine24BitIntsToUlongs(IList<int> ints)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.Count / 2; ++i)
    {
        yield return (ulong)(ints[i*2] & 0xFFFFFF) | ((ulong)(ints[i*2+1] & 0xFFFFFF) << 24);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
int[] ints = {0x00123456, 0x00456789};

ulong[] ulongs = Combine24BitIntsToUlongs(ints).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", ulongs[0]); // 456789123456
```